# Weird biased random number generation with randomR

Tags: haskell

I assume I am doing something wrong here:

```
ghci> take 10 $ randomRs (1,6) (mkStdGen 2)
[6,4,1,5,4,2,2,2,2,3]
ghci> take 10 $ randomRs (1,6) (mkStdGen 3)
[6,4,5,4,4,2,1,1,5,1]
ghci> take 10 $ randomRs (1,6) (mkStdGen 5)
[6,2,2,1,3,2,5,1,5,4]
ghci> take 10 $ randomRs (1,6) (mkStdGen 7)
[6,1,4,5,3,2,3,6,6,6]
ghci> take 10 $ randomRs (1,6) (mkStdGen 11)
[6,4,4,6,1,2,6,5,6,5]
```

Why is the first random number always "randomly" 6 ... ?

Same pattern with "n" for letters from a to z:

```
ghci> take 10 $ randomRs ('a','z') (mkStdGen 13)
"nnofwbxbtw"
ghci> take 10 $ randomRs ('a','z') (mkStdGen 17)
"novkmtfugl"
ghci> take 10 $ randomRs ('a','z') (mkStdGen 19)
"nhurafjvey"
```

I stumbled upon this working through LYAHFGG (chapter 9 on randomness) and really fail to make sense of it. I would expect no pattern across seeds.

Comment: That certainly is weird behavior, considering `length $ takeWhile ((== 6) . head . randomRs (1, 6) . mkStdGen) [1..]` is `53667`.  It takes that long to get a generator that doesn't return 6 as its first element.  I seem to remember others noticing some problems with `System.Random`'s true (pseudo)randomness.

Comment: AFAIK, `StdGen` is just a simple linear congruential generator. I'm curious but not massively surprised that it's not especially random near the beginning.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: a primitve implementation also came to my mind - though this is very extreme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.Random.StdGen` is a horrible generator that should have been replaced long ago.  There are even quickcheck properties that are obviously false which still pass after thousands of checks because of the poor quality of `StdGen` - and that is done with good seeding.

There are numerous strong generators both of a cryptographic variety and a statistical.  Consider using the `tf-random` package for one proposed replacement to `StdGen`, `DRBG` for a cryptographic random generator, or `mersenne-random-pure64` for a fast and statistically good generator.

Comment: At least the mersenne twister, though it's undoubtably useful for some applications, is with regard to this particular issue actually _worse_ than a simple LCRG: similar start conditions will yield a whole strand of similar results until they diverge. It's pretty expensive to adress this issue (not to speak of the twister's rather absurdly big state...)

Answer (score 3):

Those seeds are all *very small numbers*, as in, much smaller than `maxBound :: Int`. They are thus very much not a representative sample of real-world internal states for the random generator. And basically, the first result of `randomR` is only "as random as the seed", WRT the respective ranges.

If you want variation in the first result, you'll need to properly hash the seed, so the values are decently scattered across the permitted integer range. The easiest way to do that is to discard the first result.

Comment: But all this is because `StdGen` is a horrible generator.  He is justified in expecting distinct random streams from distinct seeds no matter the value.  `random` is a broken package and we can't replace `StdGen` with the one from `tf-random` fast enough.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you're right. Still – those _are_ also horrible seeds... it's not really the purpose of a random generator to also be a good hash function in its first iteration, so one _should_ use properly "scattered" seeds. (Again you might say, `mkStdGen` should include a proper hash function!)